# error in sending Json array to server using AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, json, http-post, arrays, afnetworking-2

I am trying to send the Json array using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to the server. Here is my Json array format

```
{
    "friendList": [
      {"id": 1, "username": "user1", "name":"person1", "friendUsername":"fUser1", "friendName":"fName1"},
      {"id": 2, "username": "user2", "name":"person2", "friendUserID":"fUser2", "friendName":"fName2"},
      {"id": 3, "username": "user3", "name":"person3", "friendUserID":"fUser3", "friendName":"fName3"},...
    ]
}
```

Here is my code to send the Json to the server

```
    NSMutableArray *friendsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSDictionary *params1 = @{@"id": @"1",
                             @"username":@"user1",
                             @"name":@"person1",
                             @"friendUsername":@"fUser1",
                             @"friendName":@"ffName1"};

    NSDictionary *params2 = @{@"id": @"2",
                             @"username":@"user2",
                             @"name":@"person2",
                             @"friendUsername":@"fUser2",
                             @"friendName":@"ffName2"};

    NSDictionary *params3 = @{@"id": @"3",
                             @"username":@"user3",
                             @"name":@"person3",
                             @"friendUsername":@"fUser3",
                             @"friendName":@"ffName3"};

    [friendsArray addObject:params1];
    [friendsArray addObject:params2];
    [friendsArray addObject:params3];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"friendsList":friendsArray};
NSLog(@"%@", parameters);

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"http://localhost:8080/RestWebServices/Rest/Post" parameters:parameters    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.response);
}];
```

I am getting the this error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)`

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. My code seems correct to me. Please help.

EDIT:

this is log i am getting

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x8b63c40 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
2014-01-09 21:57:25.497 ServerJsonParsingExample[1431:70b] status code = 400
2014-01-09 21:57:25.497 ServerJsonParsingExample[1431:70b] for operation: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8e611e0> { URL: http://localhost:8080/RestfulWebServices/Rest/Seemo } { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain";
    Date = "Thu, 09 Jan 2014 16:27:25 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} }
```

I have added to the code but still the error remains

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.requestSerializer = serializer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will work....

```
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/RestWebServices/Rest/Post"];
   [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
   [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];    
    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;

    [httpClient postPath:nil parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

            }];
```

Comment: I am using AFNetworking 2. Your code is from earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me and it looks you have created the JSON object very much right. Have you checked what the server is returning in `responseObject`. I guess `responseObject` is not the valid JSON and generating this error.

Comment: Hey, did you check the JSON coming from server?

Comment: I have added the response coming from the server please check the edit above

Comment: I donot see the JSON type of object in your response/log. It seems your server is not sending the JSON correctly.

Comment: I created the client in server side and tested the response if gives me correct json, I don't know why it gives "text/plain" as content-type. When I sending the GET request it works perfectly and gives me correct json response from iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

On your server side ensure you've set the correct content type to "application/json". I had the same issue because one of my calls was missing a content type header showing the response was JSON.